# Show text if Section is suppressed

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to display a certain message in the Report Header section based off if the Report Footer section is suppressed.

I need something like... ifSuppressed()

Does something exist like that in Crystal Reports?

In case something similar does not exist... here is my ultimate goal.

I need a value to be determined in the Report Footer section. If said value is greater than another value then I need a message to be displayed in the header.

The problem which I believe is that one of the values used in the calculation in the footer is from a sub report which I had to put in the Page Header to get what I needed. Therefore, I could not pass the value above the Page Header to the Report Header so I am trying to see if I could determine if a section is suppressed (Which is based off some variables in the sub report) and go from there.

Sorry if that is confusing and can elaborate if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course after I post a question... I typically figure it out.

So here it is.

I created another formula to grab the SUM I was looking for with the running total. 
I also created a formula to grab the amount I need to compare to (Which was from the subreport).

I then created an additional header so I have now header 1 and header 2. I put the subreport in header 1 and the two formulas in header 2. This way I can grab the sum and pass the number from the footer to the header because the subreport is above in header 1.

I then could do my comparison and display my message correctly.